# Remote Debugging with Yii and PHPStorm/Idea

Tags: php, frameworks, debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have found a few articles online about debugging Yii (PHP) applications either locally or remotely. All the examples I can find are either the code and server are local (which is easy to setup), or all code is remote (which wasn't able to work for me).

Basically all my code lives locally through an NFS file mount on a remote server, which runs apache. On the remote server (redhat) I have XDebug setup and installed with php5, but locally (Mac Snow Leopard) is my code and I don't have a web server setup. I am currently using PHPStorm as my IDE and at home (this environment is at work) I can setup debugging fine with apache (Ubuntu). But I cannot seem to get anything to work when trying to do this remotely at work and was hoping the brains here might be able to help me out.

Comment: Did you already read http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/03/configure-php-debugging-in-phpstorm-2-0/ and 
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/ ?

Comment: debugging is for sissies.  use error_log()  :D

Comment: Yes I did read those links as well as a few others. Due to how my environment is setup I needed to set the right config in php.ini for XDebug. But there is still an issue/bug which im waiting on a response for separately from here. Once I get it all working I will update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bust guess is that your xdebug.remote_host parmaters in your local php.ini are not configured.  See the [xdebug docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host) for more information.

Comment: Yea i was missing one flag, but still didn't work due to another issue.

Comment: Just wanted to update, to say that my remote php.ini config was incorrect. After looking over the xdebug docs and some issues on idea, i managed to get it working. Thanks. The actual issues was needing to allow it to be dbugged from any ip. which meant I had to turn this off on production. So in my sites ini files, i reset the xdebug settings when php was loaded for that vhost, to disable debuggin on production, still allowing me to use my development domain to test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using lighttpd with Xdebug in my remote server and Komodo IDE local behind a router and a NAT table. Additionally local I've an Apache 2 and Xdebug and Komodo IDE too and it was never a problem to debug. The problem is when I want to remote debug there wasn't any connection to xdebug. The solution was to open a reverse shell to tunnel the remote xdebug port to my localhost port. For this setting you need a ssh user account to the remote machine and tell ssh to open a reverse shell with the port 9000 to your localhost.